# Dayz on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, games, steam

I recently bought the game Dayz on my computer using Steam. I have recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my computer, and it says Dayz can't be played on my platform. I am a Ubuntu beginner. Is there anything I can do to get it to play in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

DayZ doesn't run natively on Linux, only on Windows.

There is a way to run Windows applications on Linux, using Wine.  You can think of Wine like a Windows emulator, which it fundamentally isn't (Wine Is Not an Emulator).  To install Wine, install it through the Software Center or open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get install wine`.

To find out how well an application runs in Wine, check out [WineHQ](http://winehq.org).  The entry for DayZ is [here](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=29534), and it appears that it's playable, but with some serious issues.  Of course, you'll have to install Steam for Windows through Wine, which is well documented [here](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=19444).

You may have better luck installing a more modern Wine version than Ubuntu ships with, which you can acquire by the instructions [here](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu).

The way I see it, you have three options:

- Dual-boot with Windows and play DayZ on there
- Try and get it running in Wine and work around the issues
- Have another Windows computer in your house and use Steam In-Home Streaming

More info on the latter [here](https://steamcommunity.com/groups/homestream).  Currently closed beta, but if you sign up you'll get an invite within a week.